# Binding DataRow to TextBox

Tags: c#, data-binding

I want to bind textbox to single DataRow object (passed to dialog form for editing). Here is my code:

```
DataRow row = myDataTable.NewRow();
EditForm form = new EditForm(row);

//in EditForm constructor
nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", row, "name");
```

and I'm gettinh an error: Cannot bind to property or column in DataSource. Do you know what I'm missing or any workarounds maybe?

[Added]

My DataTable for sure contains DataColumn with ColumnName="name". Here is my code for creating DataTable

```
    public DataTable SelectReturnDataTable(string tableName, string sql, params SQLiteParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                foreach (SQLiteParameter p in parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);                                        

                conn.Open();                    
                da.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does 'row' have a 'name' column?

Comment: have you tried binding with datatable instead?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with creating a DataBinding when you want to use a DataRow. I'm experiencing the same thing. I create a NewRow() and want to use it to bind textboxes directly to the row's columns. Then, when 'Save' is clicked, I add the DataRow to the DataTable...MS doesn't want us doing this evidently.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DataView dv = myDataTable.DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "id=1";

nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",dv,"NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this (with VS 2008 SP1), and I get an InvalidCastException if the row has null data in the name column, but the program continues and works.

In order to get the same exception as you, I have to make a mistake in the column name when binding. So I feel compelled to repeat @Henk's question, or ask that you show how you create the DataTable.

Comment: I'm aware of InvalidCastException. To avoid it I go with: Binding b = nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", row, "name"); b.NullValue = "";

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload for creating a DataBinding which takes in an object to use in case the source object is DBNull. You might want to try that.